# Realtek r8191SU driver for kernel >= 3.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I'm trying to build driver for my WiFi dongle which reports as rtl8191SU, however with no luck as the [official drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2292) from RealTek seems only to go to kernel version 3.0.2, while the current version of my kernel is 3.10...

Moreover this is on arm64 architecture (see [Pine 64](https://www.pine64.com/) project).

The official drivers give multiple errors when compiling e.g.:

```
field 'xmit_tasklet' has incomplete type

field 'recv_tasklet' has incomplete type

...
```

which seems to be due to kernel version mismatch.

The driver in question seems to be in fact rtl8712, which is what is downloaded from the realtek website in the end.
Is there some new version of this driver for Ubuntu and newer kernels, or alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might Google rtl8191su. I found a lot of driver hits.

Here's one you might check out...

https://github.com/chunkeey/rtl8192su

Cheers, Al

Comment: This looks promising, I don't know why my google searches failed me but most of the hits were only forums and non-working crap. Thanks, I will try it out and report back.

Comment: Please rate my answer by clicking the up arrow shown in my answer. Thanks! Al

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to build this driver because of missing symbol but it doesn't seem like fault of the driver and it may be useful to others.

Comment: Do you have the Linux header files installed? Can you say what the exact error was? An error, or a warning? Cheers, Al

Comment: I have full kernel source compiled and sources linked. The exact error was (after disabling PCI in makefile): `rtlwifi/wifi.h:1363:40: error: 'NUM_NL80211_BAND' undeclared here struct ieee80211_supported_band bands[NUM_NL80211_BANDS]`.. I have went further and fixed this, but then I got error that `ether_addr_copy` was undefined.

Comment: I briefly downloaded the driver source, and had the same error messages as you indicate. Time to go back to Google, do a little digging, and find yourself another driver to try. Cheers, Al

Comment: thanks for trying out, at least I know it's not the issue with kernel configuration or something alike.. will try different source for driver then.